# How can I give pages URLs with two layers of slashes in them?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, url

I have a page at `www.website.com/page51` with 0 layers of slash items in the URL (only the website and the page alias) and I want to make it have two layers of slash items, as in `www.website.com/layer1/layer2/page51` where `/layer1/` is layer 1 and `/layer2/` is layer 2 and `page51` is the page alias but also looks like layer 3.

**Solution that almost worked but failed:**

1. Make a menu `invisible` and create a menu header called `layer1`.  Add a menu item to `invisible` called `page51` that links to the `page51` page and make it's parent `layer1`.  (Up to this part worked, I can now go to `www.website.com/layer1/page51` to see page51)
2. Make a menu header in `invisible` called `layer2`, and make it's parent `layer1`, set the parent item of the `page51` menu item to `layer2`
   so that `invisible` is a menu which contains the menu header `layer1` with a child menu header called `layer2` which has a child menu item called `page51` but when I go to `www.website.com/layer1/layer2/page51` I get an error when that path should show the `page51` page.

Apparently, the method above works for child items but does not work for grand child items.  How do I achieve this logical structure of my website pages?